# jQuery UI how to set draggable containment option on parent's parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

The jQuery UI Draggable interaction has a nice property for [setting the containment](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment) as the parent.

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ containment: 'parent' });
```

I wish to set the containment as the parent's parent.  There is no string value to accomplish this, as string the options are

> 'parent', 'document', 'window', [x1, y1, x2, y2]

I could calculate x1,y1,x2,y2 of the parent's parent at page load and use those values to set boundaries for a container relative to the document.  But the container position can change relative to the parent's parent position if the window is resized after page load.  The native 'parent' option keeps the draggable element within the parent element regardless of window resizing.

Is there a way to accomplish this draggable containment using the parent's parent?
.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment), the `containment` option can also be a jquery selector or an actual element. So you can do this:

```
$('.selector').draggable({
    containment: $('.selector').parent().parent()
});
```

Or even better yet:

```
$('.selector').each(function(){
    $(this).draggable({
        containment: $(this).parent().parent()
    });
});
```

Comment: I attempted to do this for a sortable table, but $(this).parent().parent() did not work. Any other suggestions? My TRs within my tbody are sortable, and I would like to confine them to within the entire table.

Answer (score 4):

According to the docs, you do not *have to* pass in a string for the `containment` property. You can pass in any of:

```
Selector, Element, String, Array
```

So, just select the parent's parent with jQuery (i.e. `$( ".selector" ).parent().parent()`), and pass in instead of `'parent'`.

Answer (score 1):

If i use `$(this).parent()` my element go over the parent element.

```
$('.selector').draggable({
  containment: $(this).parent()
});
```

But with `parent` it works fine.

```
$('.selector').draggable({
  containment: "parent"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine as well:

```
$('.selector').draggable({
    containment: "#parent",
    scroll: false
});
```